# Why VSTO Add-in for Excel project not running on MAC machines

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in, macos-sierra, excel-addins

I have created VSTO Add-in for Excel with MS-Excel 2013 template, It is working great on Windows machines but not running on MAC machines

I have developed my project with the help of C# technology.
Can you guys help to run mine project on MAC machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO is not supported on Mac machines because it is based on the COM technology which is not available on Mac. 
With Mac, you can only extend excel with VBA addins.

Comment: Thank you @Malick Is there any approach to do this without moving from C#?

Comment: No, there is no way to develop an add-in with C# for mac.

Comment: Can you suggest me which technology is most suitable to develop addin for MS Excel, and that will run on all operating systems, and one more thing I badly need a strong collection set (like Datatable, Sorted list in C#).

Comment: The only technology that is cross platform is VBA. You'll be limited by its ability. Also you can call some C/C++ code via VBA if you want.